# Error in the build. gradle ( Multiple dex files define )

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException:
> >     Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzeg;

when running the app!

But I guess the problem is in the gradle. I searched for the solution, I found that there may be different versions of play service declarations. But I didn't find any errors there!

Please help me to resolve the problem. I am new to Firebase and dependencies.

This is my build gradle (app):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the build.gradle(project) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eaglewap.cleancity"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.2.2'
    //Firebase UI
    // Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you using:

```
// Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
```

is the same as using:

```
// FirebaseUI Database only
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'

// FirebaseUI Auth only
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'

// FirebaseUI Storage only
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.3.0'
```

which is in the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies), it says that it needs Firebase/Play Service Version 11.0.4. But you instead using 11.2.2, so the firebase-ui library will include its transitive dependencies, which is using 11.0.4. Hence the clash happened.

So you can use the Firebase/Play Service Version 11.0.4 or you can add play service Auth.

For the Auth, you need to include the play service version:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2"
```

Comment: Change the `com.google.firebase` version, not remove them.

Comment: I changed the versions of firebase to 11.0.4 it's working! since I'm new to Firebase and Dependencies I m in hard time and wasting lot of time in resolving it. what's the good practise for it?

Comment: For Firebase, don't use the latest version just because it's the new one. Use only the version that you need. For the dependencies, you need to dig deeper in the library documentation and try to read its build.gradle. You need to read about transitive dependencies and excluding the library dependencies. This is my 2 cent opinion.